# Numeral.js File Not Found

Tags: javascript, numeral.js

I am following the [instruction](http://numeraljs.com/) to use Numeral.js.

I insert `<script src="numeral.min.js"></script>` before the end of my `<body>`.

when I reload the page i get the following error:

```
GET file:///<project_path>/numeral.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

And if I use `numeral(1000).format('0,0')` I get `ReferenceError: numeral is not defined`

same problem if I use `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>`:

```
GET file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

What am I doing wrong? how do you use `numeral.js`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to either :

- specify `https://` instead of `//` at the beginning of the cdn url
- copy `numeral.min.js` next to your html file on disk

---

`//` means "use the same scheme as current page"

If you opened your html file by opening the file from your disk in your browser, it's url will be a `file://` url, hence the error when you tried accessing the file with `//<cdn>/...`

An alternate way is to start a webserver on your machine and access your page through `http(s)://localhost:someport/my test.html`